# Getting a message about target packages being configured multiple times. How does this happen? Never had it happen on any other distro but Ubuntu?

Tags: apt

I am receiving this when I install stuff.

How can I resolve this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge-dev.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-edge.list:3
```

Comment: Read the output. It is in plain language. "Target X is configured multiple times in A and B". Compare A and B to see how you did this. Delete one of them.